How to utilize the system-ui font as a fall-back with TailwindCSS?
I'd like to fall back to the system-ui font if for whatever reason the primary font cannot be loaded from my web application.
Here is a snippet of my TailwindCSS config...
fontFamily: {
  'sans': ['Poppins', 'sans-serif'],
},

Currently it falls back to sans-serif, but I would prefer if it would fall back to the user's font choice set by their system.
